# Validation plugin with jQuery UI Dialog only firing validation once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, validation, knockout.js

I have an ASP.NET Web Form with fields bound to a data model using KnockoutJS. I am using the Knockout validation plugin to validate.

The user has the ability to add multiple phone numbers to their application and I am using UI dialog to prompt them. My problem is that when validation is triggered it lets the user know: "must enter more than 2 digits", which I applied the max property on my model for phone number. Validation is only triggered once though and the user can bypass by just hitting accept twice.

I have attached a jsfiddle to display the problem.

```
<h3>Phone Number</h3>

<input type="button" value="Add New Phone" data-bind="click: AddPhone" />
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: PhoneNumbers">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: PhoneNumber_Number"></td>
        <td data-bind="click: $root.EditPhone">Edit</td>
        <td data-bind="click: $root.DeletePhone">Delete</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div data-bind="jqDialog: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, title:      'Phone Number' },
                template: { name: 'addPhoneNumberDialog', data: EdittingPhone, 'if':    EdittingPhone },
                openDialog: EdittingPhone"></div>


<script id="addPhoneNumberDialog" type="text/html">
    <div class="addPhoneNumberDialog">                    
    <p><span>Type:</span> <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlApplicantPhoneType"    data-bind="value: PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID, selectedText: PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName">   </asp:DropDownList></p> 
    <p><span>Number:</span> <input id="txtApplicantPhone" data-bind="value: PhoneNumber_Number" class="required phoneUS" /></p>                    
    <input type="button" class="acceptButton" value="Accept" data-bind="jqButton: {}, click: $root.OnAcceptPhoneEdit" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-bind="jqButton: {}, click: $root.OnCancelPhoneEdit" />
    </div>
</script>

//custom binding to initialize a jQuery UI dialog
ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

    //handle disposal
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).dialog("destroy");
    });

    $(element).dialog(options);
}
};

//custom binding handler that opens/closes the dialog
ko.bindingHandlers.openDialog = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (value) {
        $(element).dialog({
            appendTo: $('form:first'),
            open: function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            }
        });
        $(element).dialog('open');
    } else {
        $(element).dialog("close");
    }
}
};

var Application = function () {
var self = this;
this.Application_USCitizen = ko.observable(false);
this.Application_FirstName = ko.observable('').extend({
    required: true
});
this.Application_MiddleName = ko.observable('');
this.Application_LastName = ko.observable('');

this.PhoneNumbers = ko.observableArray([]);

this.SelectedPhone = undefined;
this.EdittingPhone = ko.observable();
this.AddPhone = function () {
    self.EdittingPhone(new PhoneNumber());
}
this.EditPhone = function (phone) {
    self.SelectedPhone = phone;
    self.EdittingPhone(new PhoneNumber().Copy(phone));
}
this.DeletePhone = function (phone) {
    self.PhoneNumbers.remove(phone);
}
this.OnAcceptPhoneEdit = function () {
    var editted = self.EdittingPhone();
    if (self.SelectedPhone != undefined) {
        self.SelectedPhone.Copy(editted);
    } else {
        self.PhoneNumbers.push(editted);
    }

    self.SelectedPhone = undefined;
    self.EdittingPhone(undefined);
}
this.OnCancelPhoneEdit = function () {
    self.SelectedPhone = undefined;
    self.EdittingPhone(undefined);
}
};

var PhoneNumber = function () {
var self = this;
this.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID = ko.observable(0);
this.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName = ko.observable('');
this.PhoneNumber_Number = ko.observable('').extend({
    max: 2
});

this.Copy = function (phone) {
    self.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID(phone.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID())
    self.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName(phone.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName())
    self.PhoneNumber_Number(phone.PhoneNumber_Number());

    return self;
}
};

var vm = new Application();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bjk964/wc7Vf/

Comment: The JSFiddle is great, but please include the *relevant* code in the question as well (so that if the link rots this question will remain useful to others). In addition, it would help if you tell us what you've tried and researched.

Comment: @Jeroen good point. I have updated with the code from the fiddle thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation lib does not automatic stop your buttons from firing, you need to use ko.validation.group and check if there are any validation errors from your click handler

http://jsfiddle.net/wc7Vf/1/

```
var PhoneNumber = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID = ko.observable(0);
    this.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName = ko.observable('');
    this.PhoneNumber_Number = ko.observable('').extend({
        max: 2
    });

    this.Copy = function (phone) {
        self.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID(phone.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeID())
        self.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName(phone.PhoneNumber_PhoneTypeName())
        self.PhoneNumber_Number(phone.PhoneNumber_Number());

        return self;
    }

    this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders. This seems to be doing the trick. I am going to test it a little more and then mark as answer if everything checks out. Thanks again.

Comment: You can also add a computed and bind the enable binding on the accept button so you can't even click while not valid